# How to obtain a presentation for each group of order $64$

Tags: finite-groups, gap, group-presentation

I am new to his forum, and would like to know how to obtain a presentation for each group of order $64$. I wish to do this for all the groups of order $64$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are $267$ of them, so you certainly have your work cut out for you.

Comment: @ Tobias, thanks. Any idea on where to get a reference that gives the presentation of each group?

Comment: If you want _abelian_ groups of order $64$, then that's a different story.

Comment: @ Arthur, am particularly interested in the non-abelian ones as the abelian ones are easy to obtain.

Comment: They might be listed in Berkovich, but possibly not in one place. I don't recall if GAP can give presentations in a nice way.

Answer (score 4):

For example in GAP:

```
l:=List(AllSmallGroups(64),x->Image(IsomorphismFpGroup(x)));;
List(l,RelatorsOfFpGroup);
```

These presentations are on comparatively many generators, if you want smaller generating sets replace the first line by:

```
l:=List(AllSmallGroups(64),
  x->Image(IsomorphismFpGroupByGenerators(x,MinimalGeneratingSet(x))));;
l:=List(l,x->Image(IsomorphismSimplifiedFpGroup(x)));;
```

(Note that these reduced presentations are just *some* presentations, not necessarily in any way canonical ones.)

Comment: To add to Ahulpke's answer (as his later answer only gives the generators), **to obtain the relators, use the command below:**

RR:=[];;
for i in l do
    Add(RR,RelatorsOfFpGroup(i));
od;


So, you get the set of generators from the suggestion of Ahulpke above, and the relators using the code above.

As Tobias mentioned, there are a total of $267$ such groups.

For example, typing l[5] (from the suggestion of Ahulpke above) shows you the set of generators of the fifth group of order 64, and typing RR[5] gives the corresponding relators for that group.

Comment: @ Ahulpke and Chuks, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Here they are.  Copy to your own LaTeX file.

```
$<a|a^{64}>$
$<a,b|b^{-1}a^{-1}ba,a^8,b^8>$
$<a,b|b^{-1}a^3ba,a^{-3}b^{-1}a^{-1}b,a^{-4}b^{-1}aba^{-1},b^8>$
$<a,b|b^2,(aba^{-1}b)^2,a^8,(ba)^2a(ba^{-1})^2a^{-1},a^3ba^{-4}ba>$
$<a,b|b^4,a^{-1}b^{-2}ab^{-2},a^{-2}ba^2b,(a^{-1}b^{-1}ab^{-1})^2,a^8>$
$<a,b|b^2,ba^2ba^{-2},a^8,(ba^{-1})^4(ba)^4>$
$<a,b|b^4,ab^2a^{-1}b^{-2},a^2b^{-1}a^{-2}b,b^{-1}a^{-1}(b^{-1}a)^2ba^{-1},a^8>$
$<a,b|b^2,a^4,baba^{-1}(a^{-1}b)^2a^{-2},(ba^{-1}ba)^2(ba^{-1})^4>$
$<a,b|b^4,a^4,b^{-2}ab^{-2}a^{-1},b^{-2}ab^{-2}a^{-1},b^{-1}ab^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-1},(ab)^2a^{-1}ba^{-1}b^{-1},(a^{-1}ba^2b^{-1}a^{-1})^2
>$
$<a,b|b^2,a^{-1}(ba)^2a(ba^{-1})^2,aba^{-1}(ba)^3a>$
$<a,b|b^4,b^{-2}ab^{-2}a^{-1},a^2b^{-2}a^2,b^{-1}a^{-1}(b^{-1}a)^2ba^{-1},a^2b^{-1}(a^{-2}b)^3,a^2b^{-1}a^{-4}b^{-1}a^2b^{-2}>$
$<a,b|b^2,(ba^{-2})^2,a^8,ba^{-1}ba^{-1}(ba)^6,(a^{-1}bab)^4>$
$<a,b|b^4,a^{-1}b^{-2}ab^{-2},ba^2b^{-1}a^2,abab^{-1}(a^{-1}b)^2,a^8>$
$<a,b|b^4,b^2a^{-1}b^{-2}a,ab^{-1}a^2ba,a^{-1}b^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-1}bab^{-1},a^8>$
$<a,b|b^{-3}aba^{-1},b^2ab^2a^{-1},a^8,ba^{-3}b^{-1}a^3b^2>$
$<a,b|a^{-1}bab,b^8,a^8>$
$<a,b|b^4,ba^{-1}b^{-2}ab,a^{-1}b^{-1}a^2ba^{-1},aba^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}bab^{-1},b^{-1}a^{-1}(b^{-1}a)^2b^{-1}a^{-1},a^8>$
$<a,b|b^4,a^4,a^{-1}b^{-1}ab^2ab^{-1}a^{-1},ab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}aba^{-1}b,(b^{-1}a)^2(ba)^2>$
$<a,b|a^{-1}b^2ab^2,b^{-1}a^2ba^2,(a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b)^2,(b^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-1})^2,a^{-2}b^{-2}a^{-1}b^2a^{-1},a^8,b^8>$
$<a,b|a^4,b^4,ba^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2},ba^{-1}b^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-1}ba,(b^{-2}a^{-1})^4>$
$<a,b|a^4,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,a^{-1}b^2ab^2,(ab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1})^2,b^8>$
$<a,b|ba^{-2}b^{-1}a^2,a^{-1}b^2ab^2,a^4b^{-4},a^4b^4,(ab^{-1}ab)^2>$
$<a,b|b^4,a^4,b^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-2}a,(a^{-1}b)^4,(ba^{-1}ba)^2,(b^{-1}a^{-1}ba)^2,(a^{-1}ba^2ba^{-1})^2,
(a^{-1}ba^2b^{-1}a^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b|b^4,a^{-1}b^{-2}ab^{-2},aba^2b^{-1}a,(a^{-1}b^{-1}ab^{-1})^2,a^8>$
$<a,b|a^4,a^{-1}b^{-2}ab^2,(abab^{-1})^2,a^{-1}b^{-1}aba^{-1}bab^{-1},b^{-2}(b^{-1}a^{-2})^2,b^8>$
$<a,b|b^4,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba,a^{16}>$
$<a,b|b^4,b^2a^{-1}b^{-2}a,a^{-2}ba^2b^{-1},a^{-6}b^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1}>$
$<a,b|b^4,a^3b^{-1}ab,ba(ab)^3,a^2b^{-1}a^{-1}b^2a^{-1}b^{-1}>$
$<a,b|b^2,ba^2ba^{-2},(ba)^2(ba^{-1})^2,a^{16}>$
$<a,b|b^2,(baba^{-1})^2,(ba)^2a(ba^{-1})^2a^{-1},(ba^2)^2a^4>$
$<a,b|b^2,ba(ba^{-1})^2ba,a^2(a^2b)^2a^2>$
$<a,b|b^2,a^4,(baba^{-1})^2,(a^{-1}bab)^2,(ba^{-2})^4,(ab)^8>$
$<a,b|b^4,a^4,b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-2}ab^{-1},(b^{-1}a^{-1})^3ba^{-1},(ba^{-1}ba)^2,(b^{-1}aba^{-1})^2,(a^2b)^4,(a^2ba^2b^{-1})^2
>$
$<a,b|b^2,a^4,(ba)^4,a^{-1}(ba^2)^2ba^{-2}ba^{-1},(a^{-1}bab)^4>$
$<a,b|b^4,b^4,a^4,b^2ab^{-2}a^{-1},baba^{-1}b^{-1}aba^{-1},(a^{-1}b)^4,(a^2b)^4,(b^{-1}a^2ba^2)^2>$
$<a,b|b^2,(ba)^3ba^{-3},ba^{-1}ba(ba^{-1})^2a^{-2},(a^{-1}b)^3a^3b,(ba^2)^4>$
$<a,b|b^4,b^{-1}ab^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-1},ab^2a^3,(ba^{-1})^3b^{-1}a^{-1},b^{-1}a^{-1}baba^{-1}ba,aba^2(ba^{-2})^2ba>$
$<a,b|b^2,a^4,a^{-1}ba^2ba^{-1},(ba^{-1})^8(ba)^8>$
$<a,b|b^4,a^4,a^{-1}b^{-1}a^2ba^{-1},b^{-2}ab^{-2}a^{-1},b^{-2}a^{-3}b^{-2}a^{-1},a^{-1}b^{-1}a(bab^{-1}a^{-1})^2baba^{-1}b>$
$<a,b|b^2,ba^{-2}ba^2,a^8,baba(ba^{-1})^6>$
$<a,b|b^2,a^4,aba^{-1}(a^{-1}b)^2a^{-2}b,(ba^{-1})^6baba>$
$<a,b|b^2,(ba^2)^2,a^8,(a^{-1}b)^5aba^{-1}bab>$
$<a,b|b^4,a^4b^{-2},a^2ba^{-2}b,(ab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1})^3ab^{-1}a^{-1}b>$
$<a,b|b^4,a^{-1}bab,a^{16}>$
$<a,b|a^{-1}b^2ab^2,a^{-1}b^{-3}ab,a^6(ab^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b|a^4,bab^{-3}a^{-1},ba^2b^2ab^{-1}a,a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-2}b^3ab^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1}>$
$<a,b|a^4,b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a,a^2b^{-1}a^{-2}b,b^{16}>$
$<a,b|a^4,a^{-1}b^{-1}a^2ba^{-1},ab^2a^{-1}b^2,(b^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-1})^2,b^2ab^{-3}a^{-1}b^3>$
$<a,b|b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a,a^8,a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^7a^{-2}>$
$<a,b|b^2,ba^{-1}ba,a^{32}>$
$<a,b|b^2,a^{-2}ba^2b,(ba)^2a^{14}>$
$<a,b|a^2,b^2,(ab)^{32}>$
$<a,b|b^2,a^4,aba^{-2}ba,(ab)^9(a^{-1}b)^7>$
$<a,b|b^2a^{-2},a^4,b^4,(ba)^{15}b^{-1}a>$
$<a,b,c|c^4,b^4,a^4,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,a^4,cb^{-1}cb,ca^{-1}ca,b^4,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,ba^{-1}b^{-2}ab,ba^{-1}(b^{-1}a)^2ba^{-1},
b^2a^{-3}b^{-2}a^{-1},b(a^{-1}ba^{-1})^2b>$
$<a,b,c|b^4,a^4,c^4,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,b^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-2}a,c^2b^{-1}a^{-1}ba,
b^{-2}a^{-3}b^{-2}a^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|b^4,a^4,c^4,(a^{-1}c^{-1})^2,a^2c^2,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,ba^{-1}b^{-2}ab,c^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,a^{-1}(ba)^2ba^{-1}b>$
$<a,b,c|bcb^{-1}c^{-1},c^4,b^4,a^4,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,ac^{-2}b^{-1}ab,bab^{-1}cac,b^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-2}a,
b^{-2}a^{-3}b^{-2}a^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,a^4,a^4,a^4,(cb)^2,(a^{-2}b)^2,aca^{-2}ca,(ba^{-1}ca)^2,(ba^{-1}ba)^2,(ca^{-1})^4,
(bcabca^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,a^4,b^4,cb^{-1}cb,a^{-1}bab,bab^{-2}a^{-1}b,aca^{-2}ca,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,(ca^{-1})^4>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,bc^{-1}bc,c^4,a^4,ca^{-1}c^{-2}ac,(a^{-2}b)^2,aca^{-2}c^{-1}a,caba^{-1}bc,a^2c^{-3}a^{-2}c^{-1},
(cac^{-1}a^{-1})^2,c(a^{-1}c^{-1})^2a^{-1}ca^{-1},a^{-2}(c^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c|a^4,b^4,c^4,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,b^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-2}a,c^{-1}a^{-1}cab^{-2},a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,c^{-2}a^{-1}c^{-2}a,
a^{-2}c^{-1}a^{-2}c,c^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-1}bc^{-1},a^{-2}b^{-3}a^{-2}b^{-1},a^{-2}c^{-3}a^{-2}c^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|b^4,a^4,c^4,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,c^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-1}ab,a^{-2}ca^{-2}c^{-1},cba^{-1}b^{-1}ac,a^{-2}c^{-1}a^{-2}c,
ba^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-2}a,c^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1}b^2a,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b>$
$<a,b,c|a^4,c^4,b^4,a^{-1}cac,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,a^{-1}bab,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,a^{-2}c^{-1}a^{-2}c,abab^{-2}a^{-2}b^{-1},
acac^{-2}a^{-2}c^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,b^4,b^2a^2,cb^{-1}cb,acb^{-2}ca,aca^{-1}b^{-1}aca^{-1}b,(a^{-1}b^{-1}ab^{-1})^2,
b^2aba^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-1},(ca^{-1})^4,(caca^{-1})^2,((a^{-1}b^{-1})^2c)^2,(ca^{-1}cba^{-1}b)^2>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,a^4,(b^{-1}a^{-1})^2,cb^{-1}cb,(b^{-1}a)^2,b^4,aca^{-2}ca,(ca^{-1})^2(ca)^2,
cb^{-1}a^{-1}ca^{-1}bcba^{-1}ca^{-1}b^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|b^4,b^2a^2,c^4,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,ab^{-1}c^{-2}a^{-1}b,b^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-2}ba,b^{-1}a^{-1}c^2b^{-1}a^{-1},
acb^{-2}c^{-1}a,c^{-2}a^2c^{-1}a^{-2}c^{-1},(ac^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1})^2,(c^{-1}a^{-1}ca^{-1})^2,(c^{-1}aca^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c|c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,(b^{-1}a)^2,a^4,c^4,b^4,aca^{-2}c^{-1}a,ca^{-1}c^{-2}ac,bc^2a^{-2}b,
c(a^{-1}c^{-1})^2a^{-1}ca^{-1},a^{-2}(c^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1})^2,(cac^{-1}a^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c|b^2a^{-2},b^4,b^2a^2,c^4,a^{-1}cac,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,(a^{-1}b^{-1}ab^{-1})^2,a^{-1}ca^{-1}c^{-2}a^{-2}c^{-1},
(a^{-1}b^{-1})^2c^{-1}(a^{-1}b^{-1})^2c,(c^{-1}b)^2ab^{-1}ac^{-2}aba^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|b^4,(b^{-1}a^{-1})^2,a^4,c^4,a^{-1}cac,(b^{-1}a)^2,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,ab^3ab^{-1},a^{-2}c^{-1}a^{-2}c,
acac^{-2}a^{-2}c^{-1},c^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-2}c^{-1}b^{-2}c^{-2}a^2b^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|a^4,c^4,a^{-1}cac,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,bac^{-2}ba,a^{-1}c^{-2}ba^{-1}b,a^{-1}c^{-2}ac^2,ba^{-1}b^{-2}ab,
b^{-1}aba^{-1}bab^{-1}a^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^2,c^2,(ac)^4,(ba)^4,(cb)^4,(acabc)^2,((cb)^2a)^2,((ba)^2c)^2>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,a^4,ba^2b,baba^{-1},a^4,aca^{-2}ca,ca^{-1}cbca^{-1}cb^{-1},(ca^{-1})^4,(cbcb^{-1})^2,
(acb^{-1}a^{-1}cb^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^2,c^4,babc^{-2}a,c^{-1}ac^{-1}bcac^{-1}b,(bc)^4,(c^{-1}aca)^2,(ac)^4,(c^{-1}bcb)^2,
(ac^{-1}b)^4>$
$<a,b,c|ca^2c,bab^{-1}a,c^2b^2,a^{-1}b^{-2}a^{-1},c^2a^{-2},c^2b^{-2},cbca^{-1}c^{-1}bca^{-1},(c^{-1}b)^4,
c(a^{-1}c^{-1})^2ac^{-1}a^{-1},(acb^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1}b^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,b^4,ba^{-1}ba,a^4,(b^{-2}c)^2,a^{-2}ba^{-2}b^{-1},cba^{-1}b^{-1}ca^{-1},(cb)^4,(b^{-1}a^2b^{-1})^2,
cb^{-1}ca^{-1}ba^{-1}cab^{-1}cba^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^4,c^4,a^4,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca^{-1},(bc^{-2})^2,ba^{-1}c^2ba,(a^{-2}b)^2,bc^2a^{-1}ba,(c^{-1}bcb)^2,
(cb)^2a^2cbc^{-1}aba>$
$<a,b,c|c^4,c^2b^{-2},c^2b^2,a^4,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca^{-1},a^{-1}bab,bab^{-2}a^{-1}b,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,
c^{-1}b^{-1}(c^{-1}b)^2c^{-1}b^{-1},(cb^{-1})^2a^{-1}(cb^{-1})^2a,cbc^{-1}a^2cbca^{-2}>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b,a^4,b^4,b^{-1}ca^{-1}cb^{-1}a,a^{-1}b^{-2}ca^{-1}c,a^{-1}cacb^{-1}a^2b^{-1},
b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}aca^{-1}ca,(cbcb^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c|a^4,a^{-1}c^2a^{-1},b^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1},b^4,bc^{-1}acba^{-1},ca^{-1}c^{-1}b^{-1}ab^{-1},acab^{-2}c^{-1},
bca^{-1}c^{-1}a^{-1}b,(ac^{-1})^4,(c^{-1}bcb^{-1})^2,b^{-1}c^{-1}b^{-1}ac^{-1}bcba^{-1}c,bcbc^{-1}bcaba^{-1}c>$
$<a,b,c|a^4,c^4,cac^{-1}ba^{-1}b,bc^{-1}a^{-2}bc,ba^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-2}a,c^2ba^{-1}b^{-1}a,a^{-2}c^{-1}a^2c,
c^{-1}a^{-1}c^2ac^{-1},a^2cbc^{-1}b,b^{-2}a^{-1}b^2a,bcb^{-2}c^{-1}b,ca^2c(cb^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,ca^{-1}ca,ab^{-1}a^{-1}b,b^4,cb^{-1}cb,a^8>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,ca^{-1}ca,b^4,cb^{-1}cb,b^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-2}a,a^{-3}b^{-1}a^{-1}b,b^{-1}a^2ba^{-2},
ba^{-1}b^{-1}abab^{-1}a^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,b^4,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba,cb^{-1}cb,a^{-1}ca^2ca^{-1},aca^3c>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,b^4,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba,ca^{-1}ca,b^{-1}cb^2cb^{-1},a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}cbc,ca^{-4}bcb^{-1},
a^{-1}cb^{-1}cba^{-3}>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,ca^{-1}ca,(cb)^2,aba^{-2}ba,(ba)^2(ba^{-1})^2,a^8>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,(cb)^2,aca^3c,aba^{-2}ba,a^{-1}(a^{-1}c)^2a^{-1},ca^{-1}ca^5,(ba)^2(ba^{-1})^2,
ca^{-1}(ca)^2ca^{-1},(caba^{-1})^2,aca^{-1}bca^{-1}cabc>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,ca^{-1}ca,aba^{-2}ba,a^{-1}bca^{-2}ba^{-1}c,(ba)^2(ba^{-1})^2,babcba^{-1}bc,(cb)^4
>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,a^4,ca^{-1}ca,(cb)^2,(ba^{-1}ba)^2,(a^{-1}b)^4,(a^{-1}ba^2ba^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^4,a^4,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,c^{-1}bcb,(ba^{-2})^2c^{-2},(ba^{-1}ba)^2,(a^{-1}b)^4>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,ca^{-1}ca,(cb)^2,(aba)^2,(a^{-1}bab)^2,a^8>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,b^4,ca^{-1}ca,cb^{-1}cb,b^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-2}a,ab^2a^3,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^2b^{-1},b^{-1}a^2ba^2,
(a^{-1}b^{-1})^2a^{-1}ba^{-1}b^{-1},(ba^{-1}ba)^2>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^4,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,c^{-1}bcb,c^{-2}a^4,(aba)^2,(ba^{-1}ba)^2>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,a^4,a^4,(cb)^2,ca^{-1}ca,a^{-1}ba^2ba^{-1},(ba)^6ba^{-1}ba^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,b^4,a^4,cb^{-1}cb,ca^{-1}ca,ba^{-1}b^{-2}ab,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,ab^{-1}a^{-1}bab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1},
b^2a^{-3}b^{-2}a^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,a^4,c^{-1}bcb,c^4,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,(a^{-2}b)^2,baba^{-1}bacba^{-1}c>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,a^4,ca^{-1}ca,(a^{-2}b)^2,ba^{-1}bcbabc,(bc)^4,babca^{-1}bacba^{-1},
bcb(cba^{-2})^2c>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,a^4,c^4,(bc)^2,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,(a^{-2}b)^2,baba^{-1}bac^{-1}ba^{-1}c>$
$<a,b,c|c^4,cbc^{-1}b,b^2c^2,b^4,a^4,bc^{-2}b,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,ba^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2},ab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}aba^{-1}b^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,(cb)^2,ca^{-1}ca,a^{-2}ba^2b,a^8,(ab)^4>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,ca^{-1}ca,a^{-1}ba^2ba^{-1},ba^{-1}bcbabc,(ab)^4,(bc)^4,baba^{-1}cbcaba^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,ca^{-1}ca,b^4,cb^{-1}cb,a^{-1}bab,a^{-1}b^3ab^{-1},a^8>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,b^4,cb^{-1}cb,a^{-1}bab,a^{-1}ca^2ca^{-1},aca^3c,cacba^3b>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,b^4,a^{-1}bab,ca^{-1}ca,b^{-1}a^{-1}bab^{-2},b^{-1}cb^2cb^{-1},ca^{-1}ba^{-3}cb,(b^{-1}c)^2(bc)^2,
a^{-1}ba^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-6}b^{-2}>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,cb^{-1}cb,a^4,ca^{-1}ca,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,a^{-1}b^3ab^{-1},b^2a^{-1}b^2a,
a^{-1}baba^{-1}b^{-1}ab^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,a^4,cbcb^{-1},ca^{-1}ca,a^{-1}bab,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,b^8>$
$<a,b,c|c^4,a^4,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,c^2b^4,c^2ba^{-1}ba,c^{-1}a^{-1}babc^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,a^4,ca^{-1}ca,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,cb^{-1}a^{-1}cb^{-1}a,b^3a^{-1}b^{-1}a,a^{-1}b^3ab^{-1},b^{-2}cb^2c,
b^8>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,cb^{-1}cb,ca^{-1}ca,a(ab^{-1})^2a,b^{-3}a^{-1}ba,ab^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-2}>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,ca^{-1}ca,cb^{-1}ca^{-1}b^{-1}a,(bc)^2b^2,a^{-1}cbcab,b^{-1}(b^{-1}c)^2b^{-1},ba^{-3}ba^{-1},
a^{-3}b^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-2}>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,ac^{-1}a^{-1}c,c^4,c^{-1}bcb,c^2ba^{-1}ba,ba^{-1}bc^{-2}a,a^8>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^4,c^{-1}bcb,a^3c^{-1}ac,c^{-2}a^{-1}c^{-2}a,c^{-1}aba^{-1}bc^{-1},ba^{-1}bac^2,a^2c^{-1}a^{-2}c,
a^8,(a^{-1}c^{-1}abc)^2>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^4,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,(c^{-2}b)^2,bc^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1}ba,a^{-2}ba^2b,c^{-1}bcba^{-4},c^{-1}bcba^4>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2a^{-2},ca^{-1}c^{-1}a,c^{-1}bcb,a^8,(ba)^2(ba^{-1})^2,bc^{-3}a^{-2}bc^{-3}>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,(c^{-1}a^{-1})^2,c^2a^{-2},c^{-1}bcb,a(c^{-1}b)^2a,ac(cb)^2ac^{-1},a^8,(ba)^2(ba^{-1})^2,
(ac^{-1})^2a^{-2}bc^{-2}b>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,a^{-1}c^2a^{-1},(c^{-1}a^{-1})^2,ba^{-1}cabc^{-1},aba^{-2}ba,a^8,(ba^{-1})^2(ba)^2,(bc^{-4})^2>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^4,c^2a^2,a^{-1}c^2a^{-1},(ca)^2,c^{-1}bcb,aba^{-1}bac^{-1}a^{-1}baba^{-1}c,
(ba^{-1}ba(ba^{-1})^2)^2,(aba^{-1}b)^4>$
$<a,b,c|c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,a^{-2}c^2,c^2a^{-2},b^4,a^{-2}c^{-2},c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,ba^{-1}b^{-2}ab,a^{-1}cb^{-1}cba^{-1},
ab^{-1}a^{-1}bab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|c^4,a^4,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,b^4,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,b^{-1}c^2a^2b^{-1},b^{-2}a^{-1}c^2a^{-1},ba^{-1}b^{-2}ab,
ab^{-1}a^{-1}bab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,a^{-2}c^2,a^{-2}c^{-2},bc^{-1}bc,a^{-1}c^{-1}a^{-1}caca^{-1}c,aba^{-1}c^{-1}aba^{-1}c,
bc^{-1}acba(ba^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c|c^{-2}a^{-2},a^4,a^{-2}c^2,b^4,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,c^{-2}ba^{-2}b^{-1},b^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-2}a,c^{-1}b^{-2}a^{-1}ca,
ac^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-2}c,b(ab^{-1})^2a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,(a^{-1}c)^2,a^4,c^4,(c^{-1}a^{-1})^2,c^{-1}bcb,a^{-1}ba^2ba^{-1},c^2(a^{-1}b)^3ab>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,cac^{-1}a^{-1},(c^{-1}a)^2,c^{-1}bcb,a^{-1}(cb)^2a^{-1},(a^{-1}c^{-1})^2c^{-4},acbc(ab)^2a^{-1}b>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,(c^{-1}a^{-1})^2,c^2a^{-2},c^{-1}bcb,a^{-1}(cb)^2a^{-1},c^8,c^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1}c^{-1}baba^{-1}b>$
$<a,b,c|aba^{-1}b,b^4,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,b^{-1}a^{-2}b^{-1}c^2,c^4a^4,c^8>$
$<a,b,c|b^4,a^{-1}bab,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,c^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}a^2b^{-1},b^{-2}a^2c^{-2},c^{-1}abab^{-1}c^{-1},c^{-1}a^2c^{-1}b^{-2},
acbacb^{-1},(a^{-1}c^{-1})^2b^{-2},(cac^{-1}a^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^2,c^2,(bc)^2,(abac)^2,(ca)^4,acbab(ca)^2(ba)^2c,(ab)^8>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^2,b^4,cb^{-1}cb,(b^{-2}a)^2,(ab)^3ab^{-1},ab^{-1}acabac,(ca)^4,
cacb^{-1}abcacbab,caca(cab^{-2})^2>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^2,c^4,c^{-1}bcb,(c^{-2}a)^2,(ac^{-1})^2(ac)^2,abac^{-1}abac,ac^{-1}(ba)^2bc^{-1}ab>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,a^4,a^4,(cb)^2,(a^{-1}ba^{-1})^2,(a^{-2}c)^2,(ba)^3ba^{-1},(aba^{-1}c)^2,(ca^{-1}ca)^2,
cacba^{-1}(cba)^2b>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,ab^2a,b^{-1}a^2b^{-1},b^4,a^4,cb^{-1}cb,a^{-1}ca^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}cab^{-1},ab^{-1}ab(a^{-1}b^{-1})^2,
(ca)^4,(caca^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^4,a^{-1}c^2a^{-1},c^{-1}bcb,a^{-1}ca^{-1}baca^{-1}b,a^{-1}(c^{-1}a)^2cac^{-1},ba(ba^{-1})^3,
c^{-1}acba^{-1}bc^{-1}abcab>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^2,c^2,(cb)^2,(ac)^4,(acbab)^2,(ab)^8>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^2,c^4,c^4,c^{-1}bcb,cac^{-2}ac,(ac^{-1})^4,(abac^{-1})^2,(ab)^2ac^{-1}bc^{-1}ab>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,a^4,(cb)^2,ca^2ca^{-2},(a^{-1}ba^{-1})^2,a^{-1}ca^{-1}ba^{-1}cab,(ba)^3ba^{-1},
cabaca^{-1}ba,(ca)^4>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^4,a^{-1}c^2a^{-1},c^{-1}bcb,abac^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1}c^{-1},a^{-1}(c^{-1}a)^2cac^{-1},ba(ba^{-1})^3,
c^{-1}a^{-1}bc^{-2}ba^{-1}c^{-1}a^2,c^{-1}acba^{-1}bc^{-1}abcab>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^2,c^2,(bc)^2,(ab)^4,(ca)^4,c(acb)^3ab>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,a^4,a^4,a^4,(cb)^2,aca^{-2}ca,aba^{-2}ba,ba^{-1}caba^{-1}ca^{-1},(ba^{-1})^4,(ca^{-1})^4,
cacba^{-1}cbacba^{-1}b>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^2,b^4,(ab)^2,cb^{-1}cb,(ac)^8>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^4,b^4,(ab)^2,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,b^{-1}abab^{-2},(cac)^2,(ac)^3ac^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,a^4,b^4,a^{-1}bab,cb^{-1}cb,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,(a^{-1}ca^{-1})^2,a(bc)^2a^{-1}b^2,(ca)^3ca^{-1},
abab^{-2}a^{-2}b^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|a^4,c^4,ac^2a,b^4,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,a^{-1}bab,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,a^{-1}c^{-1}a^{-1}c(a^{-1}c^{-1})^2,
acab^{-2}a^{-1}c^{-1}a^{-1}b^2>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^2,cbcb^{-1},b^4,(b^2a)^2,(ab)^4,acabacab^{-1},b^{-1}(ca)^3b^{-1}ca>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^4,cb^{-1}c^{-1}b,b^4,cac^{-2}ac,b^{-1}ac^2b^{-1}a,(c^{-2}a)^2,(ac^{-1})^2acac^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^2,cb^{-1}cb,bab^{-3}a,(ab^{-2})^2,b^{-1}acb^3ca,(ca)^4,(cb^{-1}a)^4>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^2,cbcb^{-1},(ab)^2,(ca)^4,b^8,cb^3(bac)^2b^{-3}aca>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,a^4,b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a,a^4,cb^{-1}cb,a^{-1}b^4a^{-1},aca^{-2}ca,a^2b^{-1}a^2b,(ca^{-1})^4>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^2,b^2(bc)^2,(cb^{-1})^2b^{-2},cb^2cb^{-2},acb^{-1}cab^{-1},(ca)^4>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^2,(b^{-1}a)^2,b^{-1}cb^{-3}c,b^8,cab^{-3}acb,(ca)^4,bcb^{-1}a(cab)^2ca>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,a^{-1}bab,a^4,cb^{-1}ca^{-2}b,ab^{-4}a,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^2b,(ca)^4,(caca^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^2,cb^{-1}cb,b^2ab^{-1}ab,b^{-1}ab^3a,(ab^{-2})^2,cacb^{-1}(ac)^2ab^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^2,(ab)^2,cb^{-1}cb,b^8,acb^{-1}abacab^{-2},b^{-2}ab^2(ca)^3c>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,aba^{-1}b,cb^{-1}cb,a^{-1}b^4a^{-1},(a^{-1}ca^{-1})^2,(ca)^3ca^{-1},a^{-1}ca^{-1}b^{-2}a^{-1}cacb^{-2}c
>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,baba^{-1},a^{-1}b^{-1}ab^{-1},a^{-1}b^2a^{-1},a^4,abab^{-1},cb^{-1}cb,a^{-1}(bc)^2a^{-1},
(ca^{-1}ca(ca^{-1})^2)^2,(aca^{-1}c)^4>$
$<a,b,c|a^{-4},a^{-1}b^{-1}ab^{-1},a^{-1}b^2a^{-1},b^2a^2,b^{-4},abab^{-1},c^4,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,cac^{-2}a^{-1}c,
aca^{-1}cac^{-1}a^{-1}c>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,a^4,b^4,a^{-1}bab,cb^{-1}cb,(a^{-1}ca^{-1})^2,b^{-2}a^{-3}b^{-2}a^{-1},(a^{-1}c)^3bab^{-1}c>$
$<a,b,c|a^4,c^4,b^4,a^{-1}bab,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,b^{-2}c^{-1}a^2c^{-1},cb^{-1}a^{-2}b^{-1}c,c^{-1}ba^{-2}c^{-1}b,
cbab^{-1}ac,b^{-1}acb^{-1}ca^{-1}c^2,ac^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1}aca^{-1}c^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,a^4,cb^{-1}cb,b^4,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1},(a^{-2}c)^2,(b^{-1}a^2b^{-1})^2,b^2(ca)^2ca^{-1}ca>$
$<a,b,c|b^{-1}c^{-1}bc,a^4,c^4,b^4,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1},bca^2cb,cb^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-1}c,a^{-1}(bc)^2a^{-1},
ac^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1}aca^{-1}c^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^2,bcbc^{-1},c^4,bac^2ba,acbac^{-2}acabc^{-2},(ac^{-1}ac)^4,(ac^{-1}ac(ac^{-1})^2)^2
>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^2,c^4,c^{-1}bcb,(ac^{-2})^2,(ab)^4,ac^{-1}abacab,abc^{-1}acac^{-1}abc^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^{-1}cbc^{-1},c^4,b^4,b^{-1}acbca,(b^{-2}a)^2,c^{-1}acac^{-1}ab^{-1}cb^{-1}a>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^4,a^4,c^{-1}bcb,cbaba^{-1}c,a^{-1}ca^{-2}c^{-1}a^{-1},c^{-2}a^{-1}bab,(a^{-2}b)^2,aba^{-2}ba,
c^{-1}acac^{-1}aca^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^4,a^4,c^{-1}bcb,ac^{-2}a^{-1}c^2,c^2(ab)^2,c^{-2}(ba)^2,a^{-1}ca^{-2}c^{-1}a^{-1},
c^{-1}acac^{-1}aca^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|a^4,b^4,b^{-2}a^2,c^4,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,a^{-1}ba^{-1}c^{-2}b,c^{-1}aca^{-1}c^{-1}a^{-1}ca^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^{-1}c^{-1}bc,cac^{-1}ab^2,c^{-1}acb^2a,cbcab^{-1}a,(ac^2)^2,b^8>$
$<a,b,c|a^4,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,c^4a^{-2},c^2ac^{-2}a,b^4a^{-2},b^2ab^{-2}a,ba^{-1}b^{-1}c^2a^{-1},cac^{-1}b^{-2}a^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^{-1}bcb^{-1},c^{-1}acb^{-2}a,b^{-1}abc^2a,ac^{-1}acb^{-2},ab^{-1}abc^2,b^2(ac^{-1})^2c^{-2},c^8
>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^{-1}ab^{-1}c^{-1}ac^{-1},ab^2cac^{-1},abcacb,b^{-2}c^{-1}b^2c,c^3b^{-1}cb,
b^{-1}ac^{-1}ab^{-1}c,acb^{-1}ab^{-1}c,cac^{-1}ab^2,c^{-1}acab^{-2},cb^{-1}c^{-1}bcbc^{-1}b^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^3b^{-1}cb,bcb^{-2}c^{-1}b,b^{-1}ac^2ba,bab^{-1}ac^2,bc^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-3},c^{-1}b^3cb,
(c^{-1}b^{-1}a)^2,(ab^{-2})^2,b^4cb^{-1}c^{-1}b>$
$<a,b,c|a^4,c^4a^{-2},c^3b^{-1}cb,c^2ac^{-2}a,c^{-1}a^{-1}b^2ca^{-1},bab^{-1}ac^{-2},c^{-1}b^{-2}cb^2,
bac^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-1},b^{-1}c^{-1}b^{-3}c>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^4,(ac)^2,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,(b^{-1}ab^{-1})^2,bab^{-1}ab^2>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,bc^{-1}b^{-1}c,c^4,(ab)^2,(ac)^2,b^8>$
$<a,b,c|a^4,a^{-1}bab,c^4,a^{-1}cac,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,ba^{-1}b^{-3}a^{-1},a^{-2}c^{-1}a^{-2}c,acac^{-2}a^{-2}c^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,(c^{-1}ba)^2,bab^{-1}ab^2,b^{-3}aba,b^{-3}(b^{-1}a)^2b^{-1},c^{-2}abac^{-1}b^4c^{-1}b
>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^4,(ac)^2,c^{-2}b^{-1}c^{-2}b,b^{-3}c^{-1}b^{-1}c,bab^{-1}ab^2,c^{-1}b^2cb^{-2},b^{-3}aba,
cb^{-1}c^{-1}bcbc^{-1}b^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|(a^{-1}b)^2,c^4,(b^{-1}a^{-1})^2,a^{-1}cac,a^4,b^2a^{-1}b^{-2}a^{-1},a^{-2}c^{-1}a^{-2}c,c^{-2}b^{-1}c^{-2}b,
c^{-1}a^{-1}bc^{-1}ab,b^{-2}c^{-1}b^2c,acac^{-2}a^{-2}c^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|b^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1},a^4,a^2b^2,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,ca^{-1}c^{-3}a,ac^{-2}a^{-1}c^{-2}>$
$<a,b,c|a^4,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,b^4,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1},b(ac^{-1})^2b,b(a^{-1}c^{-1})^2b,c^2a^{-1}c^2a,ca^{-1}c^{-1}ac^2,
b^{-2}c(ab^{-1})^2c^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c|a^{-1}b^2a^{-1},ab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1},c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,b^4,a^{-1}cac,c^8>$
$<a,b,c|a^{-1}b^2a^{-1},ab^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1},b^4,c^{-1}ba^{-1}c^{-1}ba,b^{-2}c^{-1}b^{-2}c,c^3b^{-1}cb,c^2b^{-1}c^{-2}b,
a^{-1}c^2ac^2,c^8>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,ca^{-1}ca,ba^{-1}ba,(cb)^2,a^{16}>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,(cb)^2,ca^{-1}ca,a^{-2}ba^2b,acbaba^{-1}cba^{-1}b,(ba^{-1})^2a^{-6}>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,ba^{-1}ba,ca^{-1}ca,(cb)^4,ca^{-8}bcb>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^2,c^2,(cb)^2,(ca)^2,(ba)^{16}>$
$<a,b,c|b^2,c^2,a^4,(cb)^2,ca^{-1}ca,aba^{-2}ba,(ba^{-1})^3(ba)^5>$
$<a,b,c|c^2,b^2a^{-2},b^4,a^4,cb^{-1}cb,ca^{-1}ca,(ab)^7a^{-1}b>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^2,c^4,c^{-1}bcb,c^{-1}aca,(ab)^6ac^2bab>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,b^2,c^2,(bc)^2,(abac)^2,(ab)^2a(bac)^2(ba)^3b>$
$<a,b,c|a^2,c^2,b^{-1}cbc,b^4,b^{-1}ab^2ab^{-1},b(ac)^2b,(ab)^5(ab^{-1})^3>$
$<a,b,c,d|c^2,d^2,b^4,a^4,db^{-1}db,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba,da^{-1}da,(dc)^2,ca^{-1}ca,cb^{-1}cb>$
$<a,b,c,d|d^2,b^2,c^2,a^4,da^{-1}da,ca^{-1}ca,(cb)^2,(db)^2,(dc)^2,(a^{-2}b)^2,(ba^{-1})^2(ba)^2,
bada^{-1}babdba^{-1},baca^{-1}babcba^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|c^2,d^2,a^4,b^4,da^{-1}da,a^{-1}bab,ca^{-1}ca,db^{-1}db,(dc)^2,cb^{-1}cb,a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,
abab^{-2}a^{-2}b^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^2,d^2,a^4,c^4,(db)^2,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,da^{-1}da,dc^{-1}dc,c^{-1}bcb,c^2ba^{-1}ba,(a^{-2}b)^2
>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^2,d^2,c^4,(ca)^2,c^2a^2,da^{-1}da,(db)^2,c^{-1}bcb,dc^{-1}dc,c^{-2}ba^{-2}b,(ba)^4,
badbaba^{-1}dba^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|d^2,c^4,a^4,b^4,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,a^{-1}bab,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,db^{-1}db,da^{-1}da,dc^{-1}dc,
a^{-2}c^2b^{-2},a^{-2}b^{-2}c^{-2},a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^2,a^2c^2,ac^{-1}a^{-1}c,d^4,d^{-1}a^{-1}da,c^4,c^{-1}bcb,d^{-1}bdb,d^{-1}c^{-1}dc,ba^{-1}d^2ba
>$
$<a,b,c,d|d^2,b^2,c^2,a^4,ca^{-1}ca,(dc)^2,(db)^2,(a^{-2}d)^2,(a^{-2}b)^2,ba^{-1}bdad,
cdbca^{-1}dab,(ba)^4>$
$<a,b,c,d|d^2,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb^{-1},c^4,c^2b^2,a^4,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca,a^{-1}bab,db^{-1}db,dc^{-1}dc,
a^{-2}b^{-1}a^{-2}b,(a^{-2}d)^2,da^{-1}b^2da,abab^{-2}a^{-2}b^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^2,c^2,a^4,d^4,d^{-1}bdb,a^{-1}dad,d^{-1}cdc,ca^{-1}ca,(a^{-2}b)^2,bda^{-1}d^{-1}ba,
a^{-2}d^{-1}a^{-2}d,cbd^2cb,adad^{-2}a^{-2}d^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2,(da)^2,(db)^2,(cb)^2,(dc)^2,(baca)^2,(ca)^4,(ba)^4,c(acb)^3ab>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,c^2,d^2,b^4,(da)^2,(ab)^2,cb^{-1}cb,db^{-1}db,(dc)^2,ab^{-3}ab,(ca)^4>$
$<a,b,c,d|c^2,d^2,ab^{-1}ab,a^{-1}b^2a^{-1},aba^{-1}b,a^4,db^{-1}db,(dc)^2,cb^{-1}cb,da^{-1}da,
(a^{-2}c)^2,(ca^{-1})^2(ca)^2,cada^{-1}cacdca^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,d^2,c^4,c^4,(da)^2,c^{-1}bcb,(db)^2,dc^{-1}dc,cac^{-2}ac,c(ab)^2c,(ac^{-1})^4>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,c^2,d^4,d^{-1}ada,(cb)^2,d^{-1}bdb,d^{-1}cdc,bd^{-2}aba,bacd^2bca,(ca)^4,
c(da)^2bd^{-2}cb>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,d^2,c^4,b^4,db^{-1}db,(da)^2,dc^{-1}dc,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,bac^2b^{-1}a,(b^{-2}a)^2,
b^{-1}cb^{-1}ac^{-1}a>$
$<a,b,c,d|d^2,a^4,c^4,c^2a^2,b^4,da^{-1}da,db^{-1}db,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1},dc^{-1}dc,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,
b^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-2}a,c^{-1}b^{-2}a^{-1}c^{-1}a^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,d^2,b^{-1}cbc^{-1},b^4,c^4,db^{-1}db,dc^{-1}dc,(da)^2,b^{-1}acbca,abcabc^{-1},
bac^{-1}bac,(ab^{-1})^2db^{-1}c^{-2}b^{-1}d>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,c^2,d^4,b^4,d^{-1}b^{-1}db,cb^{-1}cb,d^{-1}ada,d^{-1}cdc,d^2b^{-1}aba,(b^{-2}a)^2,
b^{-1}(ac)^2b^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,d^2,b^4,c^4,db^{-1}db,(ab)^2,(ac)^2,dc^{-1}dc,(da)^2,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb>$
$<a,b,c,d|d^2,ab^{-2}a,b^4,baba^{-1},a^{-1}cac,c^4,da^{-1}da,db^{-1}db,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,dc^{-1}dc>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,c^4,d^4,d^{-1}c^{-1}dc,(ac)^2,d^{-1}ada,c^{-1}bcb,d^{-1}bdb,d^2(ba)^2>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^2,ac^{-2}a,a^2c^2,caca^{-1},d^4,c^{-1}bcb,d^{-1}c^{-1}dc,d^{-1}a^{-1}da,d^{-1}bdb,
d^2ba^{-1}ba>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2,(dc)^2,(db)^2,babdad,cdbcabad,(ba)^4,(daca)^2,(ca)^4,
((ca)^2b)^2,cba(dac)^2bca>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,c^2,d^2,b^4,(cb^{-1})^2,(ab)^2,(dc)^2,db^{-1}db,dab^2da,dacdb^{-2}ca,(ca)^4,
cb(ca)^2bacb^{-2}a>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,d^2,b^4,cbc^{-1}b,c^2b^2,cb^{-1}cb,(ab)^2,db^{-1}db,dc^{-1}dc,cb^{-2}c,dab^2da,
ac^{-1}b^{-2}dcad,(c^{-1}aca)^2,b(ca)^2b^{-1}(c^{-1}a)^2>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,c^2,d^4,d^{-1}cdc,(ad)^2,d^{-1}bdb,cd^{-2}bcb,bdad^{-1}ba,(ca)^4,((ca)^2b)^2
>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,c^2,d^2,b^4,(dc)^2,db^{-1}db,dadb^{-1}ab,bab^{-1}dad,(b^{-2}c)^2,(bca)^2,
cbcab^{-1}a,(cb^{-1})^4,(da)^4>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,d^2,b^4,db^{-1}db,dc^{-1}dc,b^{-1}cbc,c^4,c^{-1}(ad)^2c^{-1},c^{-1}acb^{-2}a,(c^{-2}a)^2,
acb^{-1}c^{-1}ab,(b^{-2}c^{-2})^2>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,c^2,d^4,b^4,d^{-1}b^{-1}db,(ad)^2,d^{-1}cdc,(ca)^2b^2,cacb^{-2}a,d^2cb^{-1}cb,
b^{-1}adbda>$
$<a,b,c,d|c^2,d^{-1}a^{-1}da^{-1},d^4,d^2a^2,b^4,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1},d^{-1}b^{-1}db,d^{-1}cdc,a^2b^{-1}a^{-1}ba,
(b^{-2}c)^2,cba^{-1}cba,cacbab,b^{-1}cacb^{-1}a>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,c^2,b^4,d^4,d^{-1}cdc,d^{-1}b^{-1}db,(ad)^2,bad^2b^{-1}a,(b^{-1}ab^{-1})^2,cb^{-1}d^2cb,
adad^{-3},bacabc>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^2,d^2,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca^{-1},a^4,c^4,c^2a^2,(db)^2,dc^{-1}dc,abc^{-2}ba,abc^{-1}abc,
da^{-1}dbab,(da^{-1})^2(ba^{-1})^2,c^{-1}bcdada^{-1}b>$
$<a,b,c,d|d^2,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca^{-1},c^4,c^2a^2,b^4,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb^{-1},a^{-1}bab,db^{-1}db,dc^{-1}dc,
c^{-2}b^{-1}c^{-2}b,dba^{-1}b^{-1}da,(a^{-1}d)^2b^{-1}a^{-2}b^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2,(da)^2,(dc)^2,(cb)^2,dbdaba,bacdbdca,(bd)^4,(ca)^4,
c(acb)^3ab>$
$<a,b,c,d|d^2,b^2,c^2,a^4,da^{-1}da,(dc)^2,(ba^{-1})^2,(cb)^2,(a^{-2}c)^2,dba^{-2}db,cdbdca^{-1}ba,
(ca^{-1})^2(ca)^2,cada^{-1}cacdca^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^2,d^2,c^4,c^2a^{-2},c^2a^2,dc^{-1}dc,(ba^{-1})^2,da^{-1}da,c^{-1}bcb,dba^2db,
c^{-1}a^{-1}(c^{-1}a)^2c^{-1}a^{-1},((ca^{-1})^2b)^2,((ca^{-1})^2d)^2>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,c^2,d^{-1}b^{-1}db^{-1},d^4,d^2b^2,d^{-1}ada,(ab)^2,cb^{-1}cb,d^{-1}cdc,ab^{-3}ab,(ca)^4
>$
$<a,b,c,d|c^2,d^2a^{-2},a^{-1}b^2a^{-1},a^4,a^4,a^{-1}ba^{-1}b^{-1},cb^{-1}cb,(da)^2,d^{-1}b^{-1}db^{-1},d^{-1}cdc,
(a^{-2}c)^2,a^{-1}cad^{-1}a^{-1}cad,(ca^{-1})^2(ca)^2>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2c^{-2},d^2c^{-2},c^4,(dc)^2,(cb)^2,(ab)^2,d^{-1}b^{-1}db^{-1},d^{-1}ada,(c^{-1}ac^{-1})^2,
(c^{-2}a)^2,(ac^{-1})^2(ac)^2,c^{-1}ac^{-1}b^{-1}dcac^{-1}d^{-1}b>$
$<a,b,c,d|c^2,d^2,b^4,a^4,(dc)^2,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1},da^{-1}da,cb^{-1}cb,(a^{-2}c)^2,(b^{-2}d)^2,b^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-2}a,
db^{-1}a^2db,b^{-1}aca^{-1}cb^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|d^2,c^4,b^4,c^2a^2,da^{-1}da,dc^{-1}dc,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1},c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,(c^{-1}a^{-1})^2b^2,(b^{-2}d)^2,
b^{-2}(a^{-1}c^{-1})^2,db^{-1}a^2db,b^{-1}ac^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,c^2,d^{-1}ada,d^4,d^{-1}cdc,b^{-1}dbd,b^4,cb^{-1}cb,b^{-1}ab^2ab^{-1},bdab^{-1}ad^{-1},
cacb^{-1}ab^{-1},bd^2(ba)^2b,db^{-2}dcbd^2bc>$
$<a,b,c,d|c^2,a^2d^{-2},dad^{-1}a^{-1},d^2a^2,d^{-1}cdc,a^4,d^4,b^{-1}aba,b^4,cb^{-1}cb,b^{-1}dbd,
cb^{-1}acab^{-1},d^{-1}bdcb^{-1}a^2c>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,d^2c^2,dc^{-1}d^{-1}c,c^4,d^{-1}ada,b^{-1}dbd,b^4,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,c^2b^{-1}aba,
b^{-2}d^{-1}b^{-2}d,(b^{-2}a)^2,b^{-1}cb^{-1}ac^{-1}a>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,(d^{-1}c^{-1})^2,d^4,b^4,d^2c^2,d^{-1}ada,b^{-1}dbd,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,c^{-1}b^{-1}d^{-2}c^{-1}b,
c^{-1}ab^2c^{-1}a,bc^{-1}abca>$
$<a,b,c,d|bd^{-2}b,c^{-1}a^{-1}ca^{-1},a^4,d^4,dbdb^{-1},a^2c^2,a^{-1}bab,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,d^{-1}a^{-1}da,
d^{-1}c^{-1}dc>$
$<a,b,c,d|d^{-1}b^{-1}db^{-1},d^4,d^2b^2,c^4,d^{-1}a^{-1}da,a^{-1}bab,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,a^{-1}cac,d^{-1}c^{-1}dc,
c^{-2}a^2b^{-2},d^{-2}a^{-1}b^{-2}a,d^{-2}ca^2c>$
$<a,b,c,d|ac^{-2}a,a^2c^2,caca^{-1},d^{-1}c^{-1}dc,d^{-1}a^{-1}da,c^{-1}b^{-1}cb,d^4,b^{-1}dbd,
a^2b^{-1}d^2b^{-1},a^2ba^2b^{-1},a^2db^{-2}d,d^{-2}cb^2c,(b^{-1}da)^2>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2,(dc)^2,abadbd,(cba)^2,(da)^2(cb)^2,(db)^4,dabcbdca,(bc)^4,
(ca)^4>$
$<a,b,c,d|c^2,d^2,ab^{-2}a,a^4,baba^{-1},(dc)^2,(db^{-1})^2,(cab^{-1})^2,bca^2cb,ca^{-1}cda^{-1}d,
(da^2)^2,ca^{-1}c(ad)^2a>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,d^2,c^4,c^{-1}dcd,dadc^{-1}ac^{-1},bac^2ba,c^{-2}(ab)^2,cbacab,c^2(db)^2,
(ac)^2bc^{-1}bc>$
$<a,b,c,d|d^2,c^2b^2,b^{-2}a^{-2},b^4,b^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-1},dc^{-1}dc,(db^{-1})^2,b^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1}bac,
a^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}abc,a^{-1}cdacd,(da)^4,(dada^{-1})^2>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^4,d^4,b^2c^2,d^2a^2,b^{-1}dbd,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1},a^{-1}cac,d^{-1}c^{-1}dc,ca^{-1}dc^{-1}ad,
ac^{-1}da^{-1}cd,c^{-1}b^{-1}a^2cb^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^2,c^2,d^2,da^{-1}da,ba^{-1}ba,ca^{-1}ca,(db)^2,(dc)^2,(cb)^2,a^8>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^2,c^2,d^2,ca^{-1}ca,da^{-1}da,(db)^2,(dc)^2,(cb)^2,aba^3b,a^8>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^2,c^2,d^2,(db)^2,(dc)^2,ba^{-1}ba,da^{-1}da,ca^{-1}ca,bcba^{-4}c,(cb)^4,a^{-4}(bc)^2>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^2,c^2,d^2,(db)^2,ba^{-1}ba,(dc)^2,ca^{-1}ca,ada^3d,a^{-1}(a^{-1}d)^2a^{-1},
cdbada^{-1}cb,(bc)^4>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2,(da)^2,(ca)^2,(db)^2,(cb)^2,(dc)^2,(ab)^8>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^2,c^2,d^2,a^4,ca^{-1}ca,(cb)^2,(dc)^2,(db)^2,da^{-1}da,(a^{-2}b)^2,(ba^{-1})^3ba>$
$<a,b,c,d|c^2,d^2,a^{-1}b^2a^{-1},a^4,b^4,(dc)^2,ca^{-1}ca,da^{-1}da,cb^{-1}cb,db^{-1}db,
(b^{-1}a^{-1})^2b^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,d^2,c^4,(da)^2,(db)^2,c^{-1}aca,dc^{-1}dc,c^{-1}bcb,c^2(ab)^4>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2,(da)^2,(cb)^2,(db)^2,(dc)^2,(abac)^2,ac(ba)^3cb,(d(ca)^2)^2>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,c^2,d^2,cbcb^{-1},b^4,(da)^2,(dc)^2,db^{-1}db,bab^{-2}ab,b(ac)^2b,(ab^{-1})^3ab>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,c^2,d^{-1}cdc,d^4,d^{-1}ada,d^{-1}bdb,(cb)^2,cd^{-2}aca,c(ba)^3cba>$
$<a,b,c,d|a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2,(da)^2,(ca)^2,(db)^2,(cb)^2,(dc)^4,dacd(ba)^3bc>$
$<a,b,c,d|b^2,c^2,d^2,a^4,(db)^2,ca^{-1}ca,da^{-1}da,(cb)^2,(a^{-2}b)^2,a^2(dc)^2,(ba^{-1})^3ba>$
$<a,b,c,d|c^2,d^2,b^2a^{-2},a^4,b^4,ca^{-1}ca,db^{-1}db,da^{-1}da,cb^{-1}cb,db^{-2}cdc,
b^{-1}a^{-1}b(a^{-1}b^{-1})^2a^{-1}>$
$<a,b,c,d,e|d^2,b^2,c^2,e^2,a^4,(eb)^2,ba^{-1}ba,da^{-1}da,ea^{-1}ea,(ec)^2,ca^{-1}ca,(cb)^2,
(db)^2,(ed)^2,(dc)^2>$
$<a,b,c,d,e|a^2,b^2,c^2,e^2,d^2,(eb)^2,(ca)^2,(da)^2,(ea)^2,(ec)^2,(cb)^2,(db)^2,(ed)^2,(dc)^2,
(ba)^4>$
$<a,b,c,d,e|e^2,c^2,d^2,b^{-1}a^{-1}ba^{-1},b^4,b^2a^2,eb^{-1}eb,ca^{-1}ca,ea^{-1}ea,(ec)^2,cb^{-1}cb,
da^{-1}da,(ed)^2,(dc)^2,db^{-1}db>$
$<a,b,c,d,e|a^2,b^2,d^2,e^2,c^4,ec^{-1}ec,c^{-1}aca,(eb)^2,(ea)^2,(ed)^2,(da)^2,(db)^2,c^{-1}bcb,
dc^{-1}dc,c^2(ba)^2>$
$<a,b,c,d,e|a^2,b^2,c^2,e^2,d^2,(eb)^2,(ca)^2,(dc)^2,(ea)^2,(ec)^2,(db)^2,(ed)^2,babdad,
cdbcabad,(ba)^4>$
$<a,b,c,d,e|a^2,e^2,d^2,c^4,bc^{-2}b,(ea)^2,(ab)^2,cbcb^{-1},(ed)^2,ec^{-1}ec,c^{-1}aca,eb^{-1}eb,
dc^{-1}dc,db^{-1}db,dab^2da>$
$<a,b,c,d,e|a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2,e^4,e^{-1}cec,(ca)^2,e^{-1}beb,e^{-1}aea,(dc)^2,(db)^2,e^{-1}ded,
e^2(da)^2,adbabd,cbe^2cb>$
$<a,b,c,d,e,f|a^2,b^2,c^2,f^2,e^2,d^2,(ba)^2,(fa)^2,(ea)^2,(eb)^2,(ca)^2,(da)^2,(db)^2,(ec)^2,
(fb)^2,(cb)^2,(dc)^2,(fd)^2,(fc)^2,(fe)^2,(ed)^2>$
```

Comment: @ Jim, thanks. Can you please tell me how you obtained thie simplified presentations in case I hope to do it some day for groups of higher orders?

Comment: @Stan I used a similar procedure to the one described in ahulpke's answer, and then converted the GAP output to LaTeX.

Comment: @ Jim, that sounds interesting. Can you pls describe a means of converting GAP output to LaTeX?

Comment: @Stan I copied the output from GAP into a text editor and then did approximately 20 search and replaces.

Comment: @ Jim, tnx. I actually thought there could be a way of doing so in GAP.

Comment: @Stan The GAP command `LaTeX` will apply to a relator and produce a string that, when printed, is LaTeX syntax. So one could write a small function to produce that table, but frankly for one-time use search/replace will be quicker. (If you're desperate for such a function let me know.)

Comment: @ Ahulpke, tnx...I figured out a way of doing it.

Comment: @ahulpke and all: please note that the code for `LaTeX` is in `lib/obsolete.gi` so it may disappear in some future release. But one could look at that code to implement own functionality for generating LaTeX source. See also [Obtaining LaTeX Representations of Objects](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap27.html#X78024C8087F3E07F)